# how to remove &#0; in a response document in oracle service bus?

Tags: xml, xquery, osb, oracle-service-bus

I'm getting this response document when calling a service with osb:

```
<FML32>
<FLD_ERRORCODE>5801</FLD_ERRORCODE>
<FLD_ROUTINGFLAG>&#0;</FLD_ROUTINGFLAG>
<FLD_ROUTEDDESTINATION></FLD_ROUTEDDESTINATION>
<FLD_ERRORMESSAGE>Wrong platform for CDR: 78</FLD_ERRORMESSAGE>
</FML32>
```

I need to remove the **&#0;** thing (I think is a null value) and replace it with some other value but when I add a replace action and then I test the service I get the same xml response, this is what actually I'm doing at the message flow at the response action:

```
if (contains($body/registerResponse/reg/routingFlag,'&#0;')) 
then (
    replace ./registerResponse/reg/routingFlag in variable body with '000'
    checked Replace node contents
)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the xml into text message format using `bea:serialize` function available in OSB and then use the replace function to remove the `&#0` and then the resultant text can be converted into xml using `bea:inlinedXML` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't match the XML sample.

Assuming that is not the problem, try without the contains .. just do if( $body/FML32/FLD_ROUTINGFLAG/**text()** = '�').

Comment: Tried that, every time that I use the $body variable I get this document response when testing the proxy service:
`<soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
          <register>
               <response>
                   <code>9999</code>
                   <description>
                         Failure while unmarshalling message: Failed to parse XML text
                    </description>
                </response>
                <reg/>
           </register>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: It seems that I can't access that variable because of the bad format of that XML.

Answer (score 0):

You are tying to use $body/registerResponse/reg/routingFlag, but I don't see the same in the response XML that you shared. Can you please check if you have posted the correct XML?